# Android Broadcast Receiver, Update ListView

Tags: android, listview, broadcast-receiver

Возникли проблемы при обновлении *list view* из *broadcast receiver'a*.

Есть *listView* на фрагменте, есть *ConnectionChangeReceiver*.

Нужно, при изменении коннекта у девайса (доступа в интернет), показывать в *LV* что-то похожее на "Нету доступа в интернет", или, наоборот, убирать эту надпись.

Проблема в том, что я обновлял *LV*, к примеру вот так:

```
JournalFragment journalFragment = (JournalFragment) ((MainActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(JournalFragment.TAG);
    (journalFragment).updateLV();
```

но из метода `onReceive` я никак не могу получить `MainActivity`, там есть `context`, конечно, но я не могу его представить как `(MainActivity) context`.

Что делать ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно описать класс расширяющий ресивер, внутри того класса, в котором есть метод обновления списка. Тогда из этого внутреннего класса можно будет дергать методы, класса в котором он описан.

-UPD- код для регистрации ресивера

```
LocalBroadcastManager
.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).registerReceiver(new Имя_Ресивера(), IntentFilter(Тут заголовок на который будет реагировать ресивер))
```

Решил еще отправку сообщения добавить для полной прозрачности

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(new Intent(Тут заголовок на который будет реагировать ресивер))
```

Comment: если правильно понял, то я сделал так:
внутри класса описал новый ресивер, унаследованный от первого, в нем переопределил onReceive, и вызвал метод обновления списка.
Если все верно, то не работает) мб его нужно как то зарегистрировать или где то объявить в качестве ресивера ? 

p.s. первый (основной) ресивер уже объявлен в android манифесте.

Comment: Конечно его нужно зарегистрировать. В апдейте вопроса добавил код для регистрации ресивера.