# Автоматический logout по таймеру

Tags: java, android

Я хочу, чтобы моя `app` делала автоматический полный `logout`, если ей не пользуются минуту.

Как мне это сделать?

Comment: А разве есть смысл? Просто пишите в лог интересующие события. Какие события вы хотите отобразить в лог?

Comment: Мне кажется, это можно сделать с помощью программирования.

Answer (score 1):

Это очень просто. Можно переопределить метод onPause в активити и написать в нем запуск сервиса с таймером. Так же переопределить onStart на оставновку сервиса. Если минута прошла и сервис не остановлен, значит нужно послать сообщение через ресивер и сделать логаут. Если что то не понятно, спрашивай.
[Про ресивер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/436842/android-broadcast-receiver-update-listview/436895#436895)
[Про сервис](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/services-theory.php)

Comment: можете пожалуйста написат пример кода с таимером? метод onPause:                                                                                        protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        AppLogic.hideProgressBar();

Comment: А что именно не понятно? Таймер в сервисе это просто AsyncTask с Thread.sleep на минуту.